Complex layout - two variable height columns
I'm trying to create the following document and I'm running into trouble. Sketch below.

Block A and Block B are frames, makes perfect sense. Always the same height and width
Block C and D have text and tables that are variable length. Text should not flow from Block C to Block D. These are currently frames.
Block E is also a frame and is sometimes too high or too low on the page depending on the heights of C and D. Block E should flow right after C and D

To solve this I think Block C, D and E should be in the same frame and then somehow use flowables to achieve this layout. I thought about using a table to achieve this layout but then I would be nesting tables within tables, which doesn't seem like a great idea.
I'm really not sure how I can accomplish this. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.
----------------                           ----------------
|  Block A     |                           |  Block B     |
| Fixed height |                           | Fixed height |
----------------                           ----------------

------------------------------   --------------------------
|                            |   |                        |
|                            |   |                        |
|                            |   |                        |
|        Block C             |   |         Block D        |
|    Variable Height         |   |     Variable Height    |
|     Fixed Width            |   |     Fixed Width        |
|                            |   |                        |
|                            |   |                        |
|                            |   |                        |
|                            |   |                        |
------------------------------   --------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                     Block E                             |
|             (Fixed height and width)                    |
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
-----------------------------------------------------------


Nesting tables is a good idea. Your layout walks like a table and quacks like a table and should probably be a table.
